# SuiteCRM: dropdowns for custom importable module only

Tags: module, customization, suitecrm

Is it possible to create dropdowns local to a custom module (not visible no other modules), which will be exported in a tarball and will be importable with a custom module?

Comment: can you explain/provide further details of the task? also, mention what you have done so far to develop it on your end?

Comment: @Star when creating a module in Module Builder and fields for that module i have to choose dropdowns from "global pool", those dropdowns are global. Sorry, i mentioned it in the subject line only, so i will edit the body, --- can i create dropdowns local to a custom module?